Will Windows 1x query both DNS servers upon an NXDOMAIN response from the preferred one?
I have a case where DNS1 can respond to example1.com queries (it may be authoritative or not) and DNS2 similarly to example2.com.
My question(*): if both are defined as DNS servers in Windows 10 or 11, will the second one be queried if the first one answers with NXDOMAIN?
Microsoft has an extensive page about DNS but

it dates from 2008
is confusing about their usage of "positive", "negative", "successful", ... nomenclature
seems to address the redundancy of DNS servers from an availability perspective, and not from a useability/response type one.


(*) there is a preferred ordering of the DNS servers but the question stands for round-robin kind of queries (if there is such a setting). This is why I use "first" as in "first to respond"

The article seems quite clear to me: NXDOMAIN is a "negative answer". Furthermore, "If at any point the DNS Client service receives a negative response from a server, it removes every server on that adapter from consideration during this search."

They way I've always understood it, its not DNS answers like NXDOMAIN that causes windows to fail-over to the secondary DNS server address, but that it will do so if it fails to receive a response, or if the response indicates a server error (NXDOMAIN is not an error, its just a response). so windows will only use one of the two server addresses, and will only change which one it is using if the server is thought to be non-functional. https://serverfault.com/questions/84291/how-does-windows-decide-which-dns-server-to-use-when-resolving-names
